# scipy.optimize: faster root finding over 2D grid

Tags: numpy, scipy, equation-solving

I wrote some code using scipy to find the root the following equation:

```
def equation(x, y):
     return (x / y) * np.log((a * x / b) + 1.0) - 2.0 * c * c
```

with a, b, and c scalars.

I have values for y on a rectangular grid (say Y, shape 300x200), and need to find the corresponding x solving the equation for each point. I also have a starting estimate for the value of x at each point (X0, shape 300x 200)

At the moment I've managed to solve this by looping through each item in the array Y, and calling:

```
for index, value in np.ndenumerate(Y):
    result[index] = scipy.optimize.newton(equation, X0[index], args=(value))
    # or other scalar solvers like brentq
```

This works but too slow to allow me to release my script. Given the fact that the values are organised on a grid and the Y and result array contain "continuous" values e.g. gradually changing from the edge of the array towards the center I am sure there must be a nice array oriented / multi dimensional way to solve that problem, which could also give better performance.

I have tried a number of options but have not succeeded so far. Any idea?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are `a`, `b` and `c` constants? Do you need to solve these equations repeatedly, or only once?

Comment: I need to solve this about 10 times. Each time, a,b,c are constant over the whole grid, but their value can change at every iteration. At the moment I am trying to optimise the speed of the "results" array creation so  that additional slow loop can be ignored and a,b,c treated as constants and scalars.

Comment: Then you can solve it once for a range of `y` values, and interpolate.

Comment: My answer isn't very helpful, as I think you have to do what @Zhenya is suggesting.  You could just solve on `Y[::10,::10]` or something, and then interpolate on `Y`, if `Y` is as smooth as you've claimed.  If `Y` follows a function, perhaps you can make the `equation` a 2d problem, and solve for a line of zeros.

Answer (score 2):

(expanding a comment)
As @askewchan shows in his answer, the runtime here is dominated by actually solving the equations.

Here's what I'd do here: absorb `2*c*c` as a multiplicative constant into `y`, ditto for `a/b`. What's left is an equation of the form `t log (1 + t) = z`, with `t` and `z` being related to your `x` and `y`.
Now tabulate the values of `z = t log(1 + t)` over the range you need, interpolate `t` vs `z`, and you have solutions for your equation. Notice that you only need a 1D interpolation, no matter what are the shapes of the arrays `X` and `Y`.

For interpolation, `scipy` [has a range of interpolators.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) The simplest to use is probably `interp1d`, or a `UnivariateSpline`. All of them support vectorized operations, so you can probably vectorize the evaluations. If this is enough for you performance-wise, you're all set.

Depending on the range of the values of `x` and `y` you need, you might or might not want to augment the tabulation with the explicit functional behavior at the boundaries [e.g. `t log(1 + t)` approaches `t^2` as `t->0` etc]. If you need that, have a look at  https://bitbucket.org/burovski/tabulations --- this is ugly as hell, but it works [there's some work in scipy to have a better alternative, but that's in process at the moment].

Answer (score 1):

It's tough to test without values of `Y` and `X0`, but using `np.frompyfunc` might be a little faster.  It takes a scalar function and turns it into a ufunc, which operates on arrays elementwise.

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize

a, b, c = np.random.rand(3)

def equation(x, y):
    return (x/y)*np.log((a*x/b) + 1.0) - 2.*c*c

def solver(y, x0):
    return scipy.optimize.newton(equation, x0, args=(y,))

f = np.frompyfunc(solver, 2, 1)   # 2 arrays in, 1 array out, apply solver elementwise

Y, X0 = np.random.rand(2, 300, 200)
res = f(Y, X0)
```

It still doesn't truly vectorize the process, though, and it doesn't speed it up:

```py
In [51]: timeit f(Y, X0)
1 loops, best of 3: 10.4 s per loop

In [52]: timeit OP(Y, X0, a, b, c)
1 loops, best of 3: 10.5 s per loop
```

But as far as I can tell, the speed issue does not come from the looping, but rather from the fact that you're solving the equation `Y.size` times.  I believe this is as fast as it will get if you truly solve for each value in `Y`:

```py
In [53]: timeit solver(Y[0,0], X0[0,0])
10000 loops, best of 3: 178 µs per loop

In [54]: Y.size*178e-6
Out[54]: 10.68
```

Probably you already realized this :P but you have to actually decrease the computation, by making some approximation or assumption.  Something like @Zhenya's suggestion is probably necessary, but we'd have to know a bit more about the values of `Y, X0, a, b, c`.

Comment: +1 for showing where the actual bottleneck is. I'm going to bookmark this answer and pull it up every time the *python is slow* argument shows up.